# Multi select Date Picker - LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, managed-package, jquery, date-picker

I am working on an LWC component that requires a multi-select Date Picker. Currently I have created a date picker with out-of-the box date picker.
[image]

But the out-of-the box Date Picker doesn't support selecting dates randomly. It only supports either selecting a single date or a range of dates. Is there any other way to create a multi-select date picker like the screenshot shown below?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? If you have not tried anything, start with https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datepickers/

Comment: I have already created a date picker component with input type as date, but it only supports selecting one date at a time.